# c++ Final constant strings

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, final

In Java, we can specify a string as `final` to declare 'constants'. For example

```
static final String myConst = "Hello";
```

Is the correct way to do this in c++ like this?

```
const char * const myConst = "Hello";
```

I've always seen people do this:

```
const char * myConst = "Hello";
```

But, actually, you can change what that pointer points to. So, why do people not declare the pointer as constant as well? What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: no you can't change what the pointer points to. You can change the pointer though.

Comment: FYI, in C++ you should read that backwards.  `const char * myConst` is read: "myConst is a pointer to a character that is constant".  `const char * const myConst` is read as "myConst is a constant pointer to a character that is constant".

Comment: Most of the time you see that last option, whoever wrote the declaration just didn't know any better.

Comment: @Alexandre C. Yea, that's what I meant. There is some ambiguity to what I typed. "Changing what the pointer points to" as in changing the pointer value, not changing the character string.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
const std::string myConst("Hello");
```

Comment: Don't forget the static part. To mirror Java it needs to be a static member variable (though I suppose global is fine) as it may have access restrictions that have not been made clear by the question.

Comment: @Martin: Well, if it were a static member it couldn't be initialized in the declaration either.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, `const char* const` is the correct way to declare a C-style string which you will not change.

Or better:

```
#include <string>
const std::string myConst = "Hello";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const char * myConst = "Hello";
```

This means the object pointed at cannot change.

```
char * const myConst = "Hello";
```

This means the location pointed at by the pointer cannot change, but the object's value can.

```
const char * const myConst = "Hello";
```

This means neither may change.  In my experience no one remembers this, but it's always available on the net!

Typical, three people answer in the time I write mine!

Comment: @kriss I thought in C++ there was an implicit conversion from a string literal to `char*` for backwards compatibility with C.

Comment: @kriss: the second one will cause a compiler warning if your compiler is sensible, but cannot cause an error if your compiler is compliant, because it's legal C++ for the reason Mark says.

Comment: You're all right, this is more educational:    char * const myConst = "H";

Comment: @Mark @Steve: ok warning, only paranoid types like me set -Werror as default ;-)

Comment: @cbamber85: this one is allowed and won't silent compiler (as you can can still change string pointer to).

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly understand your question. To more or less mimic the `final` Java keyword, it would be either

```
const char * const myConst = "Hello";
```

(if the pointer is not going to change), and/or:

```
const char * myConst = "Hello";
```

if the pointer may change afterwards. Finally, note that with the first version, you cannot actually change the pointer itself, because it is constant.

Answer (score 0):

With Diego's edit, yes, that the right way to write it. People typically don't declare the variable const because they don't care whether it will be modified, or, rather, trust that it won't be modified (since they *know* they don't modify it).

They declare the pointed-to const because a string literal really has const characters, so you really must assign it to a variable that has char const * values.

Answer (score 0):

Technically,

```
char * const myConst = "Hello";
```

is the most correct answer, as reassigning the pointer would leave you with a string which probably could not be recovered.

Some implementations allow you to change the characters in "Hello" (even if it's a bad idea), so the first const in

```
char const * const myConst = "Hello";
```

Is a great idea.  Personally as

```
char const * myConst = ...;
```

and
    const char * myCount = ...;

are equivalent, I tend to enforce a style guideline that the const always follows the item it modifies.  It sometimes reduces misconceptions in the long run.

That said, most people don't know how to use `const` correctly in C++, so it's either used poorly or not at all.  That's because they just use C++ as an improved C compiler.

Comment: char * const myConst = "Hello";
This doesn't define a constant C-string. This is a hack that C++ allows for compatibility with C. You are assigning a string literal to pointer to non-const string. Of course, every compiler must allow mutating operations, e.g. myConst[2] = 'a'; which is also undefined behavior.

Comment: @Gene Bushuyev: Why are you saying `myConst[2] = 'a';` is undefined behavior ? `'a'` is just a shorthand for setting a value in a numeric type char (just another way to write `myConst[2] = 97;` in ASCII environment). Why the hell setting 97 in an array would be undefined behavior ?

Answer (score 0):

> But, actually, you can change what
>   that pointer points to. So, why do
>   people not declare the pointer as
>   constant as well? What is the correct
>   way to do it?

Because it's rarely useful, more often than not you would want to have the values on the stack (pointers included) to be non-const. Get Sutter & Alexandrescu "Coding Standards" book, it explains this point.

Answer (score 0):

The real point is that programmers are compeled to declare some pointers at least as `const char *` to store char arrays between double quotes. Nothing force them (no compiler warning or error) to also make the pointer constant... as people are lazy you can draw your own conclusion. They are probably not even really trying to define a constant, they just want to shut off compiler errors (well, warning in this case).

Keeping that in mind, I would probably go for a different solution anyway:

```
const char myConst[] = "Hello";
```

The difference here is that this way I won't decay the original byte array used as string to a pointer, I will still have a byte array that can be used exactly as the original literal.

With it I can do things like `sizeof(myConst)` and get the same result as with `sizeof("Hello")`. If I change string to a pointer, sizeof would return the size of a pointer, not the size of the string...

... and obviously when doing things this way changing the pointer becomes meaningless, as there is no pointer to change anymore.